# typescript function declared a non-void type but has no return expression

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm just starting with Typescript converting some existing Angular code and I'm stuck at the first hurdle. I can't get the following to compile and I can't see what's wrong so hopefully someone will help me.

Errors:

```
Function declared a non-void return type, but has no return expression. Line 41 Col 102

Could not find symbol '$resource'. Line 49 Col 38
```

Code:

```
/// <reference path="../dt/angular/angular.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../dt/angular/angular-resource.d.ts" />


var chartAPI = angular.module('chartAPI', ['ngResource', 'ngCookies']);

// Config
chartAPI.config(['$resourceProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($resourceProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
    // Don't strip trailing slashes from calculated URLs
    $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
    // Enable HTML5 - needs HTML5 doc
    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    // Ensure CSRF token is sent in $http requests
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
}]);

interface IDRFPagedResult extends ng.resource.IResource<IDRFPagedResult> {
    count: number;
    next: string;
    previous: string;
    results: Array<any>;
}

interface IViewAsUser extends ng.resource.IResource<IViewAsUser> {
    id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
}

interface IViewAsUserList extends IDRFPagedResult {
    results: Array<IViewAsUser>;
}

interface IViewAsUserListResource extends IViewAsUserList {
    list() : IViewAsUserList;
}

chartAPI.factory('ViewAsUserList', ['$resource', function ($resource: ng.resource.IResourceService): IViewAsUserListResource => {

    var queryAction: ng.resource.IActionDescriptor = {
        method: 'GET',
        params: {},
        isArray: false
    };

    return <IViewAsUserListResource> $resource('/rest/v1/view-as-user/', {}, {
        list: queryAction
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a syntax problem on this line:

```
chartAPI.factory('ViewAsUserList', ['$resource', function ($resource: ng.resource.IResourceService): IViewAsUserListResource => {
```

Specifically this part:

```
 function ($resource: ng.resource.IResourceService): IViewAsUserListResource => {
```

You cannot combine `function` with `=>` like this -- either write `function (args) { ... }` or `(args) => { ... }`. The compiler is trying to interpret the body of the function as part of a function type literal.

Comment: Sometimes you look at code so long you miss the obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to take a look at this article

#### [AngularJS + TypeScript – using $resource to talk to a WebApi backend](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.cz/2014/07/angularjs-typescript-using-resource-to.html)

To see, that to declare our resource we need a bit different interfaces structure. This should be some item

```
interface IDRFPagedResult {
    id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    email: string;
}
```

Then we define: `IDRFPagedResourceDef` - a simple interface that only extends a resource on `IDRFPagedResult` *(see mainly `IResource<>`)*:

```
 interface IDRFPagedResourceDef extends ng.resource.IResource<IDRFPagedResult> {
 }
```

And finally Resource Class `IDRFPagedResource` on the resource definition *`IDRFPagedResourceDef`* *(see mainly `IResourceClass<>`)*

```
interface IDRFPagedResource extends ng.resource.IResourceClass<IDRFPagedResource> {
}
```

Finally, the cited resource factory definition:

```
export class ResourceBuilder{

    static $inject = ['$resource'];

    constructor(private $resource: ng.resource.IResourceService) {
    }

    public getDRFPagedResource(): IDRFPagedResource {
        return  this.$resource('/rest/v1/view-as-user/', {}, {
           // extend here, e.g. 
           // list: queryAction
       });
    }
}
```

Would suggest to read that [article](http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.cz/2014/07/angularjs-typescript-using-resource-to.html) to see that all in action